# загрузка данных из файла

Tags: mysql, windows-7

У меня mySql 8.0, я создал базу данных через консоль на локальном компьютере, создал таблицу, пытаюсь записать данные из файла тоже через консоль (windows 7) в таблицу командой

```
load data local infile 'data.txt' into table numbers;
```

но получаю ошибку

```
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

Comment: В документации https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html сказано, что такая ошибка будет в случае, если данная команда отключена в настройках и/или при компиляции MySQL или клиента MySQL

Comment: как узнать при скачивании что у него отключено? или как включить в настройках данную опцию